# How to create a new user and a txt file inside it?

Tags: useradd

I need to write a bash-script that will create a new user named  *user1*  and an empty file
*my_txt.txt*  in  *~user1/tmp/* . The problem is terminal asks the **password** for new user and i don't know how to input it along **su - user1**

Comment: I sense a homework exercise... A hint: you don't have to `su` to the new user in order to be able to create files for them.

Comment: this looks like a homework question, so I'll just ask you a question that might point you in the right direction - why do you think you need to use `su`? does the question itself require it?   Also, to create a new user, you're either already running as root or you used `sudo` or similar.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show your complete script. Hint: `chown` and `chgrp` might be useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the commentators I've written this code, and it seems to work:

```
sudo useradd -m -s "/bin/bash" user1

sudo bash -c "echo user1:password | chpasswd"

sudo -u user1 bash -c "cd /home/user1 && touch my_txt"
```